# Share same code repository

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to as if it's  possible to share same code repository in visual studio online between 2 different projects?
I need 2 seperate project boards and other things except the [code] tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple [Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams) within the same team project, each with its own backlog.